# Python: embed function for loop output on html tag

Tags: python, html, function, loops, cgi

I got a Python function that outputs a list like this,

```
def get_items(argument):    
    for item in items:
        print item
```

On the terminal, when I pass an argument to my function and print, like, "get_items(test)" I get:

```
item1
item2
item3
```

Now, I need to get this on post through storage field (I already got this part working, but I can only print variables with static content, while the content of a list inside a function will return "None"). What I need looks like this,

```
item1
item2
item3
```

In view source, it will look like this,

```
<p>
item1<br/>
item2<br/>
item3<br/>
</p>
```

I'm stomped on how to print this, which in php would be such a simple approach as embedding php within the html content. However, Python throws a 500 error anytime I try anything....
Please, help!

Comment: What is the context where this function is being called? Are you generating HTML directly with Python? Why aren't you using a web framework such as Django, Pylons or Google App Engine?

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue you're having is.  Can you post the script that is giving you trouble, and an example of the data you are supplying to it?

Comment: David, unfortunately, I am not allowed to use frameworks. I have to do this by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are executing your script as a CGI- your script MUST echo out a Content-type followed by 2 returns before anything else:

```
print "Content-Type: text/html\n"

def get_items(item):    
    for item in items:
        print item+'<br />'

print "<p>"
get_items(foo)
print "</p>"
```

Comment: OK, tMC, your answer is being extremely helpful as I ma getting somewhere. However, I have dictionary objects and lists that were removing duplicate elements in the original file and they worked fine. Now, I am getting my list of elements but including the duplicates...do you know how can I solve this?